# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on bool php mvc pdo

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pdo

I have try the following code but the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on bool
this is the controller `I have try the following code but the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object`
this is the code `<?php
class symptome
{
private $id_sym,$nom_sym;

```
public function __construct($id_sym,$nom_sym){
    $this->id_sym=$id_sym;
    $this->nom_sym=$nom_sym;
        
}

public function add($connexion){
    $connexion->exec("insert into medicale2(nom_sym) values('".$this->nom_sym."')");
    header("location:index.php?controller=symptome&action=index");
}

public function edit($connexion){
    
    $connexion->exec("update medicale2 set nom_sym='".$this->nom_sym."'");
    header("location:index.php?controller=symptome&action=index");
}

public function delete($connexion){
    $connexion->exec("delete from medicale2 where id_sym='".$this->id_sym."'");
    header("location:index.php?controller=symptome&action=index");
}

public function index($connexion){
    $res=$connexion->query("select * from medicale2")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    
    return $res;
    
}


public function detail($connexion){
    $res=$connexion->query("select * from medicale2 where id_sym='".$this->id_sym."'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $res;
}
```

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, query does not execute the SQL query.
You should execute it, before you call method 'fetchAll' on it!

```
public function index($connexion){
    $prepare=$connexion->prepare("select * from medicale2");
    $prepare->execute();
    $res=$prepare->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    
    return $res;
    
}
```

Comment: If it worked, feel free to click on the check!